# Using uom-systems in a modular Java project with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, java-module

I am working on a modular Java project that needs physical unit support. I am currently using http://www.uom.systems, but it only works in when I remove my `module-info.java` file.

Here is my `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    application
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("systems.uom:systems-common:2.1")
    implementation("systems.uom:systems-quantity:2.1")
}

application {
    mainClass.set("unitsuser.Main")
}
```

My `module-info.java`:

```
module unitsuser {
    requires si.uom.units;
}
```

And my main class (`Main.java`):

```
package unitsuser;

import javax.measure.Quantity;
import javax.measure.quantity.Length;

import tech.units.indriya.quantity.Quantities;
import tech.units.indriya.unit.Units;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Quantity<Length> len = Quantities.getQuantity(10.0, Units.METRE);
        System.out.println(len);
    }
}
```

My folder structure:

```
.
├── src/
│   └── main/
│       └── java/
│           ├── unitsuser/
│           │   └── Main.java
│           └── module-info.java
└── build.gradle.kts
```

When I run `./gradlew run`, I get this error:

```
error: module not found: javax.inject
```

I assumed this meant I had to add `javax.inject` as a dependency, so I tried adding `implementation("javax.inject:javax.inject:1")`. This caused the same error.

Edit:
The `tech.units.indriya` dependency requires the module `javax.inject`, but the artifact it's downloading to fulfill that dependency doesn't have a `module-info` file. So it's relying on an automatic module being created with the name `javax.inject`. My project is placing the `javax.inject` package in the unnamed module, when it should be an automatic module. As described on this [Grade doc page](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_modular), Gradle puts all artifacts that don't specify to use automatic modules on the unnamed module. To work around this, they recommend using artifact transformations. Does this make sense, or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is a result of an invalid module configuration in the [indriya](https://search.maven.org/artifact/tech.units/indriya/2.1.3/bundle) dependency. It requires the module called `javax.inject`, which is an automatic module generated from this [artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject/1/jar). It assumes the automatic module will be available, but the manifest in the jar doesn't have the `Automatic-Module-Name` entry. Some build systems might not care and still generate an automatic module based on the jar filename. In the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_modular):

> A third case are traditional libraries that provide no module information at all — for example commons-cli:commons-cli:1.4. Gradle puts such libraries on the classpath instead of the module path. The classpath is then treated as one module (the so called unnamed module) by Java.

So Gradle doesn't support using legacy libraries with modular projects. We need to make sure there is a `javax.inject` module available on the module path. To achieve this, we can do one of several things:

1. Use artifact transformation to add automatic module entry to the manifest,
2. Find another artifact that creates the `javax.inject` module, and add that as a dependency to the project,
3. Find another artifact that creates a module and create an alias to it with the correct module name, or
4. Make a new Maven artifact with the correct module name and upload it to a repository.

Artifact transformation is difficult to do with Gradle since you need plugins and extra code to unzip the jar and edit it. It definitely could be done, but I don't want to try it. I was unable to find any artifacts online that used the `javax.inject` module name. Most of them used `java.inject` or something else. Since I also don't want to go through the hassle of creating a new project and uploading it to a repository, I'll use the third option.

[This repo](https://github.com/pustike/javax.inject) by GitHub user [pustike](https://github.com/pustike) is a fork of the same dependency injection library that adds a module called `java.inject` that we can use to make an alias. Here are the steps to making this work with the project at hand:

#### Step 1: Multi-Project

Since we need multiple modules in the project, Gradle requires that we use a multi-project build. Your directory structure should look like this:

```
.
├── app/
│   ├── src/
│   │   └── main/
│   │       └── java/
│   │           ├── unitsuser/
│   │           │   └── Main.java
│   │           └── module-info.java
│   └── build.gradle.kts
├── injectwrapper/
│   ├── src/
│   │   └── main/
│   │       └── java/
│   │           └── module-info.java
│   └── build.gradle.kts
└── settings.gradle.kts
```

Contents of `settings.gradle.kts`:

```
rootProject.name = "unitsuser"
include("app")
include("injectwrapper")
```

#### Step 2: Configure inject wrapper

The inject wrapper project is the alias to the `java.inject` module. This must be added as a transitive dependency so the `app` project has access to the artifacts. The contents of `injectwrapper/build.gradle.kts` should be:

```
plugins {
    `java-library`
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    api("io.github.pustike:javax.inject:1.1.0")
}
```

Add the transitive dependency `injectwrapper/src/main/java/module-info.java`:

```
module javax.inject {
    requires transitive java.inject;
}
```

#### Step 3: Use the alias and uom dependencies in the main project `app`:

Add the dependencies to uom-systems and `injectwrapper` and main module and main class with `app/build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    `application`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":injectwrapper"))
    implementation("systems.uom:systems-common:2.1")
    implementation("systems.uom:systems-quantity:2.1")
    implementation("systems.uom:systems-unicode:2.1")
}

application {
    mainModule.set("unitsuser")
    mainClass.set("unitsuser.Main")
}
```

`app/src/main/java/module-info.java` must require uom-systems:

```
module unitsuser {
    requires si.uom.units;
}
```

Now that the module path is satisfied, running `./gradlew :app:run` now ouptuts `10 m`.